# C# Word - Range.InsertFIle not working

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

i tried to insert a html file to a word with Range.InsertFIle method. But it is not working. Please help me.

```
object oFalse = false;
string strFileName = @"E:\Workbook\SampleOutput\SampleOutput\SupportFiles\Report_43321100_ER.html";
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        object oTrue = true;
        object oRange = oPara1.Range;
       // oDoc.Bookmarks.Add("BookMark", oRange);
        try
        {
            oPara1.Range.InsertFile(strFileName, ref oRange, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oFalse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error like a thrown exception? If so, please include details of it.

Comment: am not getting any error. but document does not contain the required html output.

Comment: Have you tried inserting other types of files such as a plain text file?

Comment: tried but no use. Any other alternative solution also fine.

Comment: Maybe oTrue and oRange should actually be of type boolean and a Range?

Comment: no. they should be reference objects. Otherwise compile time error is occuring.

Answer (score 3):

Pass an empty string as the Range parameter (or maybe System.Reflection.Missing.Value)

The name "Range" for this parameter is misleading. It doesn't specify the range where you want to insert the file. It's not even a "Word Range". It's a "Subset name" which lets you specify which part of the file you want to insert. e.g. if you were inserting a Word document, it could be a bookmark name in the file that you are inserting. If you were inserting an Excel sheet it might be an R1C1:RnCn reference or a Range name.

Comment: `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` worked a treat for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
string strFileName = 
   @"E:\Workbook\SampleOutput\SampleOutput\SupportFiles\Report_43321100_ER.html";
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
//object oTrue = true;
//object oRange = oPara1.Range;
// oDoc.Bookmarks.Add("BookMark", oRange);
try
{
    oPara1.Range.InsertFile(strFileName);
}
    catch (Exception ex)

<...>
```